# Swift - NSDate after breaking into components always give the next day's date

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsdate

I generate 7 dates by adding days to current date. I add all the dates in an Array. 
Now when I pick any date, it pulls the correct date. Then I create components of that date. Now when I print the component, it show the date(day part) as next day's date.
So, if choose 27-05-2016, and then get its components, and when I check, component.day, it gives me 28 instead of 27.

Here is my code to generate dates :

```
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    // start with today
    let selectedDate = cal.startOfDayForDate(NSDate())

 for index in 1...7 {

        dateArray.addObject(selectedDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(Double(index)*24*60*60))

        print(dateArray.objectAtIndex(index-1))

    }
```

Here is the code where I choose a date from the above array and fetch its components :

```
 if currentIndexPosition>=0 {

        selectedDate = dateArray.objectAtIndex(currentIndexPosition) as? NSDate
    }
    else
    {
        selectedDate = dateArray.objectAtIndex(0) as? NSDate
    }

    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = cal.components([.Day , .Month, .Year, .Hour,.Minute ], fromDate: selectedDate!)
```

Now when I check the components the date is not the same that I chose from the array. Its one more than the selected date.

[image: This is what I selected from date array]
[image: But when I check its components, I get incorrect date]

Please let me know , if I missed anything or you need any other info.

Thanks

Comment: Check after set date formatter. >  Hour and minute also 0.

Comment: Indexes in Swift / ObjC start always with zero, maybe there is a confusion, and please **never** do date math using *86400*, there are dedicated (and more reliable) methods like `dateByAddingUnit:value:toDate:options` of NSCalendar.

Comment: @PayalManiyar I did not understand , hour and minute are zero, but I do not care about them. I just want the date. I am going to add hour and minute separately.

Comment: @vadian its not about the adding of days. Its about date showing correct at one place and incorrect at other place (in components)

Comment: "2016-05-28 18:30:00 UTC" is *the same point in time* as "2016-05-29 00:00:00" in your time zone! – NSDateComponents contains the values in your local timezone, and the *debugger* displays the date in UTC. There is nothing wrong! (Search for "NSDate wrong" and you'll find many similar issues.)

Comment: But @vadian is right as well: A day does not always have 24 hours, it can be 23 or 25 hours when transitioning from or to daylight savings time.

Comment: @MartinR -- Alright. It means the code is correct. Thanks